# In google Sheets How can i use the "SEARCH(search_for" Function using a range of cells?

Tags: google-sheets, full-text-search, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to output TRUE or FAlSE when searching a Cell with Txt for a range of Words

Ideal Formula but not working: =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A1:A10,A121)),TRUE,"")

What works is this : =IF(SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"happy","glad","joy"},A123)))>0,TRUE,FALSE)

The Top formula is not efficient.. Will be hard to update the formula when i need to update the search.

Comment: Have you tried `=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$1:$A$10,A121))>0, TRUE, FALSE)`

Answer (score 0):

It sure seems like this should work.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A1:A10,A123)))>0
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! But Its not working correctly , 
If i leave A123 Empty its False  if i fill it up with Anything not the Words in A1:A10 its True

Comment: if you search for "round", and your phrase is "we ran around the house" is that supposed to be true or false?

Answer (score 0):

### UPDATED ANSWER:

You can try this tweaked function:

```
=IF(A123 = "","", IF(SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A123,TEXTJOIN(" ", TRUE, A1:A10))))>0,TRUE,FALSE))
```

> This will ignore if `A123` is empty & if you fill it up with any word that's not in A1:A10, it'll return `False`. Otherwise, `True`.